# Backbone-Rails Tutorials

Tags: ruby, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Where is a good place to get started learning how to use Backbone in Rails? It seems to be all the rage nowadays. I know some basics of Rails and Backbone but I'm by no means an expert.

Comment: [The best place to start](https://www.google.com/search?q=backbone+rails+tutorials)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Please Provide tutorial url's.

Comment: Sure. Go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=backbone+rails+tutorials) and click on the links until you find something you like.

Comment: Thanks.Any books which demonstrates from scratch

Comment: Can I know whether stack overflow is for sharing the Knowledge or not? and to guide the users who stuck with their development?. 
If that is not the case please add a caption to Stackoverflow on what they are publishing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are railscasts on this topic. Its not a free episode though.

[backbone on rails part1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1)

[backbone on rails part2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2)

and [another screencast](http://www.backbonerails.com/screencasts)

Comment: Thanks for reply,Please provide best free tutorials